# Gerund or to-infinitive with proceed

Tags: gerunds

I have the following sentence and need your help:

"The EU expects PV and wind to **proceed growing** significantly in future."

Is the gerund correct here or do I have to use the to-infinitive like:

"The EU expects PV and wind to **proceed to grow** significantly in future."

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: No, "proceed" requires a _to_-infinitval complement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer BillJ. But does it not sound bad to say 'to proceed to grow' (2 times 'to' in series)

Comment: I wouldn't say so.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer BillJ